# Rubber Fails for Rails AWS Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I have a question about Rubber failing. I can get it to start making an instance but eventually I get this error message.

> failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/DormDish2-production/releases/20120116205725 && bundle install --gemfile /mnt/DormDish2-production/releases/20120116205725/Gemfile --path /mnt/DormDish2-production/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on DormDish.dormdish.com

Any ideas? My gemfile is just fine on the local machine.

Comment: I am having the same error. I was able to create the app initially but now when I deploy it gives that error. Hope you find an answer.

Comment: Can you report the versions of the software you're using? Also what OSes are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Need more info to go on. I did find this thread on a google groups titled:

- domain in config [rubber.yml](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubber-ec2/LWdDnjQUeg8)

Looks to be a similar issue to yours:

> The deployment fails. I see the following error:
>
> failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/jitesh-website-production/releases/ 
>   20120407170022 && bundle install --gemfile /mnt/jitesh-website- 
>   production/releases/20120407170022/Gemfile --path /mnt/jitesh-website-
>   production/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development 
>   test'" on webapp.foo.com

The fix was to make sure that you could access *Dormdish.dormdish.com*, this entry get's put in your `/etc/hosts` file. Can you confirm that this is the case? Also can you access that hostname via ssh on your AWS instance?

Comment: Yep, it was a problem with host file. `cap rubber:refresh` and `cap rubber:bootstrap` again after resolved my problem :)

Comment: So your issue is fixed then?

Comment: Yes, fixed. `refresh` is for clearing hosts file from rubber changes and `bootstrap` create it again with fixed values. In my case it was because I've changed domain :) ps. can't award bounty 5 more hours.